# How to check if reverse proxy is enabled once the cluster is created

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After creating a service fabric cluster is there a way to find if reverse proxy is enable for the cluster?

I have check the properties of the cluster and but did not find any details there. 
Is there any other was we can find out where this setting is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a cluster in Azure:

- Open `https://resources.azure.com` using the tree.
- Find your service fabric cluster.
- Look at the `"nodeTypes"` element.
- If it has an element named `"reverseProxyEndpointPort"` the reverse proxy is enabled (and configured to the specified port number).
- If there is no such element, the reverse proxy is not configured.

On premises:

- Look at your [clusterconfig.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest) file for the same element.

Answer (score 0):

in the portal click on "NodeType"> Select one of the Nodes one of the name you can see if Reverse Proxy is enabled.